# no longer sign-in with SSO

Tags: c#, ms-office, single-sign-on

**【Problem】**

The app was implemented by reference to below URL, can no longer sign-in with SSO.

URL: https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/omarv/2012/11/15/developing-windows-8-store-apps-for-sharepoint-online-with-sso-single-sign-on/

**【The code that was copied from above URL】**

```
const string msoHrdUrl = “https://login.microsoftonline.com/GetUserRealm.srf“;


private async Task<Uri> GetAdfsAuthUrl()

{

   // make a post request with the user’s login name to

   // MSO HRD (Home Realm Discovery) service so it can find

   // out the url of the federation service (corporate ADFS)

   // responsible for authenticating the user

   byte[] response = await HttpUtility.SendHttpRequest(

       new Uri(msoHrdUrl),

       HttpMethod.Post,

       new MemoryStream(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(String.Format(“handler = 1 & login ={ 0 }”, this.username))),

       // pass in the login name in the body of the form

       “application/x-www-form-urlencoded“,

       null);


   StreamReader sr = newStreamReader(new MemoryStream(response));

   Dictionary<String, IJsonValue> dict = new Dictionary<string, IJsonValue>();

   HttpUtility.ParseJson(JsonObject.Parse(Encoding.UTF8.GetString(response, 0, response.Length)), dict);


   // the corporate STS url is in the AuthURL element of the response body

   Uri corpAdfsProxyUrl = dict.ContainsKey(“AuthURL“) ? new Uri(dict[“AuthURL“].GetString()) : null;


   return corpAdfsProxyUrl;

}
```

**【Current Situation】**

Send POST Request to “https://login.microsoftonline.com/GetUserRealm.srf“, but I got response with error below.

> Error: "AADSTS90100: Invalid request. The Accept request parameter value 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded' is invalid."

When I changed method POST to GET and set json to Accept, I can get some values that I want and AuthURL（"https://ADFS.CONTOSO.COM/adfs/ls/?username=USER%40CONTOSO.COM&wa=wsignin1.0&wtrealm=urn%3afederation%3aMicrosoftOnline&wctx=" ）, but following behavior is different than before.

Ex) I cannot find value of “wresult” from Response that accessed to "https://ADFS.CONTOSO.COM/adfs/ls/auth/integrated/?username=USER%40CONTOSO.COM&wa=wsignin1.0&wtrealm=urn%3afederation%3aMicrosoftOnline&wctx="

**【My Question】**

I am not sure when this problem was occurred.
Does somebody have some information about this problem like this authentication function has changed?
The last time it went well is January in this year.

Comment: there have been problems today: http://downdetector.com/status/office-365. Login (50%)

Comment: Suddenly this problem disappeared, but I do not know why,,,
Still need some information,,,

Comment: it has occurred again!!!

Comment: Have the same issue. No code change our side; but this snippet of code now fails.